# JSX if/else syntax within React

Tags: reactjs, syntax, jsx

I'm trying to figure out how to add an if/else here so that if `classroomId` has a value, the `importUserToClassroom` endpoint will be hit. If not, I'd like to execute the same code, but with the `importUsers` endpoint. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong with my syntax would be much appreciated!

```
handleFormSubmit(data) {
    const {
        importUserToClassroom,
        importUsers,
        addFlashMessage,
        formatErrors,
        showUiBlocked,
        hideUiBlocked,
        match: {params: {classroomId}},
    } = this.props;
    showUiBlocked();
    const users = userDataToList(data);
    {
        classroomId !== undefined ? (
            importUserToClassroom({
                users,
                classroomId,
            })
        ) : (
            importUsers({users})
        )
    }
        .then(() => {
            hideUiBlocked();
            addFlashMessage('Users imported successfully', 'success');
            this.context.router.history.push('/users');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            hideUiBlocked();
            if (err.status !== 409) {
                return formatErrors(err).then(err => {
                    this.setState({
                        errors: err,
                    });
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    errors: {
                        usernames: err.data.message,
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Update: The following ended up working!

```
handleFormSubmit(data) {
    const {
        importUserToClassroom,
        importUsers,
        addFlashMessage,
        formatErrors,
        showUiBlocked,
        hideUiBlocked,
        match: {params: {classroomId}},
    } = this.props;
    showUiBlocked();
    const users = userDataToList(data);
    if (!isEmpty(classroomId)) {
        importUserToClassroom({
            users,
            classroomId,
        })
            .then(() => {
                hideUiBlocked();
                addFlashMessage('Users imported successfully', 'success');
                this.context.router.history.push('/users');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                hideUiBlocked();
                if (err.status !== 409) {
                    return formatErrors(err).then(err => {
                        this.setState({
                            errors: err,
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        errors: {
                            usernames: err.data.message,
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    } else {
        importUsers({users})
            .then(() => {
                hideUiBlocked();
                addFlashMessage('Users imported successfully', 'success');
                this.context.router.history.push('/users');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                hideUiBlocked();
                if (err.status !== 409) {
                    return formatErrors(err).then(err => {
                        this.setState({
                            errors: err,
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        errors: {
                            usernames: err.data.message,
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also try `typeof classroomId !== 'undefined'` instead of `classroomId !== undefined`

Comment: First, please explain more about the problem you're trying to solve. But, in general, nothing about what you're doing should be in JSX. In fact, many (and me) would argue that all your networking logic shouldn't even be in the *component*, let alone in your JSX. So, focus on making your call(s), returning some data, and then deciding based on the state of that data, what to render.

Comment: @user8227859 Can you explain the isEmpty function that you included in your updated example?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really JSX, but you do have some syntax errors. You can't use curly brackets like that. If `importUserToClassroom` and `importUsers` return promises, you could try something like this:

```
const savePromise = classroomId ? 
  importUserToClassroom({
    users,
    classroomId,
  }) :
  importUsers({users});

  savePromise.then(() => {
    hideUiBlocked();
    addFlashMessage('Users imported successfully', 'success');
    this.context.router.history.push('/users');
  })
```